# keyboard stops working

Tags: keyboard, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I am running ubuntu studio 14.04 (xfce) and sometimes my keyboard just stops working, this includes the ability to bring up the log out menu with the start button.

I believe I have experienced the same problem with xubuntu.

When this happens, the applications menu also stops working (I cannot click on it). Otherwise my touchpad works fine.

My computer is a Toshiba Satellite L730.

Thanks.

Update: So I realised that the keyboard stops working when I switched audio output (headphones to speakers) and changed the volume afterwards. This seem to be the cause and if I change the volume after that (the keys for this still work), the keyboard starts working.
Because of this I don't have much trouble any more but ill keep this open because it's a bit of a bug and id like to know if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 (xfce).

I originally thought it was because I had added SQLite Manager to Firefox (it stopped responding) however it doesn't seem to be related to that.

I find that the problem appears and if left alone will resolve itself within a few minutes.

During the period of odd-response, the mouse right-click menu may not work, possibly due to a an incorrect focus. I have found that I can click the taskbar and bring an application to the front but I cannot access the application (eg cannot write in a document, cannot left-click to move the cursor).

With the keyboard, shortcuts I have added (SUPER+L, SUPER+E) don't work but some key combinations do work (CRTL+ALT+F1). I can switch to a terminal and work in the terminal. Originally I would go to a terminal and kill X but when I realised that it would come good after a period, I now just wait.

Computer is Dell Latitude E6500.